# Extract download URL from anchor tag which is not having <href> instead js onclick Listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selenium

I want to download file from web application using selenium webdriver java.

My scenario is to get download URL from anchor tag but it’s not having href directly instead it triggers javascript onclick event.

I don’t know how to get URL from the above because its generate URL once we click the element. While searching, I found, we can use event handlers to perform the onclick function in our code but don’t know the clear information about that also.

At the same time, I have to maintain my session to download the file. I have mentioned the same below.

**My anchor tag look like this:**

```
<a class="btn btn-link withIcons btn-download" id="diversityCertxlsx" tabindex="333" onclick="javascript:viewAttachment('91779459');" role="button" data-bind-enter="true"><i class="phx phxGlyph halflings halflings-download-alt" role="img" id="halflingshalflings-download-alt"></i>&nbsp;<span class="linkText">diversityCert.xlsx</span></a>
```

**Javascript function: viewAttachment:**

```
function viewAttachment(fileId) {
    var url = "ViewAttachment?OrgId=20003679&supplierID=100193331&tmstmp=1461412880132"
    url = addUrlParameter(url,'FileId', fileId);
    window.location = url;
    }
```

Pl Provide/suggest me a solution.

Thanks

Comment: Selenium won't let you download files, it's limited to doing what the browser can do (or at least, you couldn't look at the contents of the file unless the browser opens it directly). Selenium *can* execute javascript, if that's any use to you. what sort of file/content does ViewAttachment send?

Comment: Can you give an example of a full download URL? (your desired output)

Comment: @RobGudgeon: i want to download *.xlsx. That is what i have to extract from the webelement. eg: https://domain/apps/Router/ViewAttachment?OrgId=*&supplierID=*&FileId=91779459

Comment: you probably want to read http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/ & this: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/how-to-download-a-file-using-seleniums-webdriver

Comment: @RobGudgeon Yeah i got your point. But the issue is, I'm not able get the URL from tag <a>, like i mentioned in my question above. provide me solution for that.

Comment: Anyone have solution for this ?